# SetImageBitmap from internal storage

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

How to set image Bitmap from internal storage? I checked my code and images are places internal storage, but problem with function SetImageBitmap  Any help? Below there is my code, take picture save it to internal storage.

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                 String filename=currentImagePath.substring(currentImagePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename));
                }
            }
        }


        public void takepicture() { 

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = imageFile();
                currentImagePath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.fillInStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private File imageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DEFAULT_DATETIME_FORMAT);
        String imageFileName = DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date());

        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity());
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        FileOperations.checkDirectory(directory, false);

        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", directory);
    }
}
```

Comment: You trying to store image in your external path ??

Comment: In internal:  ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity());
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: does your code generate errors ?? if so please put your log

Comment: Did you use getexterstore function

Comment: sorry can you explain in details?

Comment: Can you try passing `currentImagePath` in decodeFile() function and then check

Comment: It is a String currentImagePath

Comment: Yes i got that but what i am trying to say is that instead of passing only the name of the file, pass the whole path in this function `imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentImagePath));`

Comment: I need simple example, take picture, save to internal storage and show it. Anybody has it?